# History on ancient thoughts regarding bones and blood

Tags: biology, obsolete-theories

I heard a story about how ancient people believed that fathers contributed to the white things in a child (bones), while mothers contributed the red matter (blood). However, I found no reference regarding this in my unsuccessful internet search.

So where and when did this thought originate from, or which are the oldest references to it?

(Trivia: [It's even referenced in a song.](https://www.google.com/search?q=wolves%20without%20teeth%20lyrics))

Comment: This might be very similar: *[Honour thy father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honour_thy_father_and_thy_mother)* see quote on * Legends of the Jews Vol III*